# Error loading WebappClassLoader(Getting Error)

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jersey-2.0

I am doing a webservice using resteasy/jersy.While running on tomcat i am getting the following error but not able to figureout what is happening.I cleaned and runned project many times but it is not working.I used maven to add the dependencies.
my 
Stacktrace is given below

```
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\java\eclipse\eclipse;;.
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SnapshotHealthApp' did not find a matching property.
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9999
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 394 ms
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.43
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet jersey-serlvet as unavailable
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: /SnapshotHealthApp
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@5a384a
 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SnapshotHealthApp threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9999
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Apr 14, 2015 7:21:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 252 ms
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SnapshotHealthApp</display-name>
  <servlet>

    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.snapshothealthapp.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>snapshot</groupId>
  <artifactId>snapshot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
       </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.codesnippets4all</groupId>
    <artifactId>quick-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20141113</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <version>1.8</version>
       </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
   <finalName>SnapshotHealthApp</finalName>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.5</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
             </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

tried a lot to resolve the above error.Any help will be highly appreciated.....

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't mix Jersey versions. This

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>1.12</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   is the main dependency that will pull everything in. So you don't need

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
       <version>1.8</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Get rid of that. It will get pulled in. And change the `jersey-client` to match accordingly.
2. This

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   is a conflict. `jersey-core-1.12` repackages the JAX-RS api into its module, and the jar above conflicts with it. Get rid of that.

---

#### My other suggestions

- As I said, don't mix Jersey dependency versions. Best thing to do is keep a Maven property, and use that for all the Jersey dependencies

  ```
  <properties>
      <jersey.version>1.12<jersey.version>
  </properties>
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Unless, you have a strict requirement to use Jersey 1.12, I suggest to upgrade to 1.19. That will pull in the `jsr311:1.1.1` that you are trying to use.

---

#### Note

This might not solve the problem, as I was not able to reproduce the `ClassNotFoundException`, but I was able to produce other exceptions that were caused by your dependencies. I guess once the `ServletContainer` is loaded, it causes the other problem.

I would suggest you look into the Tomcat `webapps` dir when you deploy the app, and see if all the jars are in the `WEB-INF/lib` of your app. Maybe they are jars aren't getting built with the war.